# how to remove states from stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

After removing the states from $stateProvider and its caches from cacheTemplate,it gives me a 'already defined' error when trying to add the same state name.

```
 clearStates: function () {
        var states = this.$state.get();
        for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            if (states[i].name != 'shell.error404' &&
                states[i].name != 'shell.error500' &&
                states[i].name != 'shell' &&
                states[i].name != '') {
                var tmplUrl = states[i].templateUrl;
                if (tmplUrl) {
                    this.templateCache.remove(tmplUrl);
                }
                delete states[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 clearStates: function () {
            var states = this.$state.get();
            var itemsToBeRemoved = [];
            var removalIndex = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                if (states[i].name != 'shell.error404' &&
                    states[i].name != 'shell.error500' &&
                    states[i].name != 'shell' &&
                    states[i].name != '') {
                    var tmplUrl = states[i].templateUrl;
                    if (tmplUrl) {
                        this.templateCache.remove(tmplUrl);
                    }
                    //delete states[i];
                    itemsToBeRemoved[removalIndex++] = i;
                }
            }
            for(var j=0;j<itemsToBeRemoved.length;j++){
               states.splice(itemsToBeRemoved[j],1);
             }
        }
```

Store the index(s) to be deleted and use states.splice(>index<,1) instead of delete states[i]

delete leaves an empty element in the array at the given index, this may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: its not working at all,the same error keeps showing "state already defined".i think there is no such a workaround for ui-router.Explaining here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1095